# How to add indexes to txt file output and then modify lines using indexes Python

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file, that I can open in Python.

```
with open("database.txt", mode = "r") as text_file:
    print ("\tDatabase: ")
    for line in text_file: 
        print ("\t\t"+line[22:])
```

Now the output looks like:

```
Database:
[Sandy] [20]
[Patrick] [5]
[Spongebob] [125]
[Squid] [1200]
[Garry] [1]
```

My problem is that i need to add indexes to every line starting from 1 to length of the list.

```
Database:
1. [Sandy] [20]
2. [Patrick] [5]
n. [MrKrabs] [42]
```

And after I have to be able to change the line corresponding to the index.

```
Choose index you want to change: 1
Write down the name and the number: [MrsPuff] [300]
```

And now the Database becomes

```
Database:
[MrsPuff] [300]
[Patrick] [5]
[Spongebob] [125]
[Squid] [1200]
[Garry] [1]
```

And requirement is that the indexes are only shown in Python. The actual txt file database is without them.

I hope I will find help, because I have been trying for few hours and still can't manage it.

Comment: `for index,line in enumerate(text_file): `

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, I am pretty new to the coding overall and have no idea where to put that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printing part is relatively easy using the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
with open("database.txt", mode = "r") as text_file:
    for iline, line in enumerate(text_file, 1):
        print iline, line
```

Note the use of the second argument to start the numbering at 1, since indexing is normally 0-based in Python. You need to subtract 1 again from the user input to modify the correct line later on ...

Comment: This works as intended thanks, but now I have problem with input that asks what index i want to change. I tried this way.                                 while question in range(1,len(iline)):

Answer (score -1):

```
h = file('db.txt', 'r')
lines = h.read().split('\n')
h.close()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print index, line
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.